# Applying transformation to every item in Single<List<T>>

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a `val singleList: Single<List<EntityItem>> = ...`

I also have a custom transformer to convert `ItemEntity` to `Item`
(doing either `transformer::fromEntity` or `transformer.fromEntity(entity)`)

How would I use RxJava operators to run this transformation on each `EntityItem` in `singleList` so that `Single<List<EntityItem>>` becomes `Single<List<Item>>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.map { ... }`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#map-io.reactivex.functions.Function-) on `Single<T>` to transform the value it holds, and inside [map the items of the list](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html):

```
val result = singleList.map { it.map(transformer::fromEntity) }
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the clear explanation and a working code!